# How to change decimal separator from comma to fullstop in redshift copy command

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm working with raw data that has a comma as the decimal separator rather than fullstop (3,99 instead of 3.99). Is there a way to convert this directly in redshift copy command rather than having to upload then change afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues to consider:

- Field delimiters
- Replacing Characters

The **default delimiter** in the Amazon Redshift [`COPY`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command is a pipe character ( | ), unless the CSV option is used, in which case the default delimiter is a comma ( , ).

Thus, if your file is delimited by a non-comma character (eg a pip "|" symbol), then the comma in a number will not split across fields.

As to converting the comma into a decimal, this is **not possible**. You will need to load the field as a string, and then run an UPDATE command to copy the string into a numeric field (with a bit of character replacement too).

Alternatively, try to **pre-process** the file before loading into Redshift (eg through `sed`), so it is clean before loading into Redshift.