# importing data with commas in numeric fields into redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-copy

I am importing data into redshift using the SQL `COPY` statement. The data has comma thousands separators in the numeric fields which the `COPY` statement rejects.

The `COPY` statement has a number of options to specify field separators, date and time formats and NULL values. However I do not see anything to specify number formatting.

Do I need to preprocess the data before loading or is there a way to get redshift to parse the numbers corerctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change decimal separator from comma to fullstop in redshift copy command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274585/how-to-change-decimal-separator-from-comma-to-fullstop-in-redshift-copy-command)

Answer (score 2):

1. Import the columns as TEXT data type in a temporary table
2. Insert the temporary table to your target table. Have your SELECT statement for the INSERT replace commas with empty strings, and cast the values to the correct numeric type.